# Unable to provide proper datatype for a property using Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am getting some typescipt error for the below code, actually for the below interface, items can be object or array based on the code and response, but I am not sure on how to add datatype of array/object/any, more specifically 'any' to the items property

```
export interface Test {
  items: {
   test1: testing[],
   test2: testing[]
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean, 'items' can either be an object or an array?

Comment: @AdilKhalil Yes, you are right, here I am putting it as object but it can be an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a property to be able to have multiple types, you can do the following:

```
export interface Test {
  items: { test1: testing[], test2: testing[] } | testing[] | any
}
```

You can make it more readable by adding more interfaces:

```
export interface ItemTesting {
  test1: testing[],
  test2: testing[]
}

export interface Test {
  items: ItemTesting | testing[] | any
}
```

You can also create this into a reusable and generic `Type`:

```
export interface ItemTesting<T> {
  test1: T[],
  test2: T[]
}

export type Testing<T> = ItemTesting<T> | T[] | any;

export interface Test {
  items: Testing<testing>
}
```

<sub>(using lowercase for classes or types is frowned upon though)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new interface for every new object

```
export interface Test {
  items: Item
}
export interface Item{
   test1: testing[],
   test2: testing[]
}
export interface testing{
   key:value;
}
```